# How to pass two parameters in javascript function onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a html code for two dropdown boxes. I want to pass these two values as a parameters to a `javascript` function when we change the second dropdown (`onchange`).

Here is my code:

```js
function CatName(str1, str2) {

  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("album_name").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("album_name").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "update.php?q=" + str1 + "&q1=" + str2, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="category_name">
      <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
      <option value="Birds">Birds</option>
      <option value="Notinlist">Category Not in list</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="album_name" onchange="CatName(this.value)">
      <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
      <option value="Dove">Dove</option>
      <option value="Parrot">Parrot</option>
      <option value="Notinlist">Category Not in list</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just do something like this : `CatName(this.value, document.getElementById("id-of-the-first-select-box-here").value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its complicated to passing parameter and receiving them in function. A better option is to write one function and fetch these values using respective id or selector.

#### Sample Code

```js
function getvalue() {
  var fval = document.getElementById('category_name').value;
  alert(fval);
  var sval = document.getElementById('album_name').value;
  alert(sval);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="category_name">
        <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
        <option value="Birds">Birds</option>
        <option value="Notinlist">Category Not in list</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="album_name" onchange="getvalue();">
        <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
        <option value="Dove">Dove</option>
        <option value="Parrot">Parrot</option>
        <option value="Notinlist">Category Not in list</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please explain your changes as well.

Comment: i can understand what you mean?

Comment: You should explain what changes you have made that OP had missed. Why his code was not working etc. Just code is not a good answer.

Comment: ok its complicated to passing parameter and receiving them in function so write one function it automatically fetch value using respective id

Answer (score 1):

Giving an id for the first dropdown and get the first dropdown value by that id.
here i give an id "`categoryName`" for the first dropdown.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="form-group">
         <select class="form-control" name="category_name" id="categoryName" > 
            <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
            <option value="Birds">Birds</option>
            <option value="Notinlist">Category Not in list</option>
         </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Getting the first dropdown value by id as a parameter in `onchange` method.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="form-group"  >
         <select class="form-control" name="album_name" onchange="CatName(this.value,document.getElementById('categoryName').value)">
            <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
            <option value="Dove">Dove</option>
                <option value="Parrot">Parrot</option>
            <option value="Notinlist">Category Not in list</option>
         </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly explain what have you changed as well.

Answer (score 0):

***Check this out:***

```
$('.form-group select').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
 function CatName(val) {
    alert(val);
}
CatName(val);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/tymcb2yo/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change the HTML of your second select statement to this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="album_name" onchange="CatName(this.value, document.querySelector('select[name=category_name]').value)">
```

First, in order to pass two values, you need to actually pass the two values into your function. In the example you provided you had only passed the value of the 2nd `select` element.

Second, we need to get the value of the first `select` element, which we only know the name of. We can use the `document.querySelector()` function to get the first item that matches a given CSS selector. In this case, our selector would be `select[name=category_name]`. Then you get the value of that element with the `.value` property.

```
document.querySelector('select[name=category_name]').value
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned `jQuery`, you can have a `onChange` handler for second dropdown and on change, fetch first select's  value using `name` or `id`.

Also, you can use `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` instead.

```
var url = "update.php?q=" + str1 + "&q1=" + str2;
$.get(url, function(response){ // sucess handler })
  .error(function(exception){ // process exception });
```

---

```js
$("[name='album_name']").on("change", function CatName() {
  var category = $("[name='category_name']").val();
  var album = $(this).val();
 
  $("#result").html("<pre>" + JSON.stringify({category:category, album:album},0,4));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="category_name">
      <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
      <option value="Birds">Birds</option>
      <option value="Notinlist">Category Not in list</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="album_name">
      <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
      <option value="Dove">Dove</option>
      <option value="Parrot">Parrot</option>
      <option value="Notinlist">Category Not in list</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```